# why sticky element stop to the end of its parent

Tags: html, css

i use the property position:sticky for a box in my page
after i scroll down the box stop moving in the end of its container
although there was another space below the box

html code:

```
<div class="example">
  <div class="content one"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box fixed">fixed</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="example">
  <div class="content one"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box sticky">sticky</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

.example {
  width: 50%;
}
 
.content {
  background: #333;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1em;
}

.content.one {
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: limegreen;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

i expect that the box will come down until the end of body

Comment: https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46: _"When you define an element with position: sticky you’re automatically defining the parent element as a sticky container! This is very important to remember! The container is the scope of the sticky item, **and the item can’t get out of its sticky container.**"_

Comment: If you want position sticky to stick as well, why not just set fixed on it like you did with the other div?